# Sorting order in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

In the following query in SQLite

```
SELECT cfpref FROM cfprefs ORDER BY cfpref
```

I expect the output to be sorted in ASCII order. However, the output contains

```
GLAIC_TLC
GLAICSPW
```

in this order, even though underscore (_) in ASCII table is located after uppercase letters. Is it intentional, or is it a bug?

Comment: Good call @peterm. I did not expect that behaviour.  [NOCASE - The same as binary, except the 26 upper case characters of ASCII are folded to their lower case equivalents before the comparison is performed](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you, by any chance, use `COLLATE NOCASE` on `cfpref`?

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b4fc7/1)** demo

When you use the default `BINARY` collation you will get your expected order

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/279403/1)** demo

Comment: Yes, I was using COLLATE NOCASE